# Python: create list of tuples

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a list of tuples in django like

```
appointments = [(datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10, 30)),    
                (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 12), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 13)),    
                (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 15, 30), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 17, 10))]
```

I am iterating a django query set and storing the value in appoinments list like

```
    appoinments = [] 
    for select_meeting in get_meeting:
        getm = int(select_meeting.duration)
        appoinments += zip(((select_meeting.meeting_datetime),
                            (select_meeting.meeting_datetime + timedelta(minutes = getm))))
    print appoinments
```

But it's returning the result like that's not my requirement actually

```
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 11, 21, 5),),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 11, 22, 5),),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 11, 23, 5),),
 (datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 12, 0, 5),)]
```

Comment: Just append to the list? 
`appointments.append((select_meeting.meeting_datetime, select_meeting.meeting_datetime + timedelta(minutes = getm)))`
No need for zip or all the extra parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using zip wrong - it is actually how it works and that's normal (i-th tuple it returns contains i-th element of given iterable).
Those line should be:

```
appointments.append((select_meeting.meeting_datetime,
                     select_meeting.meeting_datetime + timedelta(minutes = getm)))
```

and it should be what you want now.

Comment: Oh, and if you want some "python magic" you can do it all in one line by using list comprehension: `appointments = [(m.meeting_datetime, m.meeting_datetime + timedelta(minutes = int(m.duration))) for m in get_meeting]`

Answer (score 0):

```
appointments = [(x, x+timedelta(minutes=x.duration)) for x in get_meeting]
```